# vim: how to replace ":" in a pattern without removing all ":"?

Tags: vim, replace

I've got this python-like text:

```
if a==0:
   print ok
   [1:]xy
```

I wish to delete all "[1:]" content. So I tried this:

```
%s/[1:]//g
```

Unfortunately, the first line is changed to be

```
if a==0
```

The ":" was eliminated, not as my expectation. So how should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim search uses regular expressions to match, `[` and `]` are special characters in regex to match sets of characters.

`[1:]` means `1` or `:`. You need to escape the brackets like: `%s/\[1:\]//g`

Answer (score 2):

Escape square brackets, like this:

```
%s/\[1:\]//g
```